# WPF DataGrid performance issue multi threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, datagrid

i have a fificult performance problem with my WPF DataGrid.
My DataGrid is very slow while loading data and scrolling on **Remote Desktop Clients** and older PC.

I load my grid on the following way:
At first i execute my sql-thread in an own thread, so that the user can interact with the application while the statement will be executed. The SQL-Statement create an `ObservableDicionary<string, string>` for every row. After creating a row, i save the dictionary in an `ObservableCollection<ObservableDicionary<string, string>>`:

```
while (cDataReader.Read() && GlobalSettings.MainThread.IsAlive && stopThread == false)
{
    ObservableDictionary<string, string> cToAdd = null;
    List<Tuple<string, string>> cTempData = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    if (myUseCheckBox)
    {
        cTempData.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("__intern_cv__", "false"));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        string cValue = "";
        string cName = cDataReader.GetName(i).ToLower();

        if (!cDataReader.IsDBNull(i))
        {
            cValue = cDataReader.GetString(i);
        }

        cTempData.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(cName, cValue));
    }

    cToAdd = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>(cTempData.ToDictionary(K => K.Item1, V => V.Item2));

    myGridPaging.RawData.Add(cToAdd);
}
```

At the same time, a second thread grabs all `ObservableDicionary<string, string>` from my ObservableCollection and copy them in tow other OvservableCollections with the names **LoadedData** and **BackgoundData** list:

```
int cCountRawData = myRawData.Count;

lock ((myGrid as SyGridViewControl).LockObject)
{
    if (cCountRawData > 0)
    {
        List<ObservableDictionary<string, string>> cList = new List<ObservableDictionary<string, string>>(myRawData.GetRange(0, cCountRawData));

        // Add all elements to the grid-paging
        if (myLoadedDatas.Count + myBackgroundDatas.Count <= myPageSize)
        {
            myGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke
                                    (
                                        (Action)delegate()
                                        {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < cCountRawData; i++)
                                            {
                                                Insert(cList[i]);
                                            }
                                        });

        }
        else
        {
            //
            InsertRangeBackgroundList(myRawData.GetRange(0, cCountRawData));
        }

        myDisplayCounterSteps += cCountRawData;
        if (myDisplayCounterSteps >= 100)
        {
            (myGrid as SyGridViewControl).RowCounter = myLoadedDatas.Count + myBackgroundDatas.Count;
            (myGrid as SyGridViewControl).DisplayRowCounter();

            myDisplayCounterSteps = 0;
        }

        // Remove all added elements
        myRawData.RemoveRange(0, cCountRawData);
    }
}
```

The Foreground list is binded to the datagrid. When i scroll down in my datagrid, i copy items from the **BackgroundDatas** list in the **LoadedDatas** list:

```
public void LoadNext()
{
    if (myCalledFromLoading)
    {
        myCalledFromLoading = false;
        return;
    }

    if (myBackgroundDatas.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (myBackgroundDatas.Count <= myPageSize)
    {
        using (ObservableCollectionEx<ObservableDictionary<string, string>> cDelayed = myBackgroundDatas.DelayNotifications())
        {
            foreach (var cObject in cDelayed)
            {
                // Add Object
                myLoadedDatas.Add(cObject);
            }
        }

        // Clear
        myBackgroundDatas.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        using (ObservableCollectionEx<ObservableDictionary<string, string>> cDelayed = myBackgroundDatas.DelayNotifications())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myPageSize; i++)
            {
                // Add Object
                myLoadedDatas.Add(cDelayed[i]);
            }
        }

        // Remove
        for (int i = 0; i < myPageSize; i++)
        {
            myBackgroundDatas.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i have the problem, that my application is very fast on local computer, but when i deploy my application to a terminal server application, it run very very slow.

The problem is special high, when i habe a lot of columns. Today i have tested
183 Columns and 10000 Rows. Loading all 10000 Rows toke about 20 seconds. The sql statement was executed in one second, so i figured out that the problem must be the binding:

```
var cColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
cColumn.Binding = new Binding("[" + Config.ColumnName.ToLower() + "]");
```

Maybe some one has an idea, how i can improve my performance...

Thank you!

Comment: You have multiple issues here. First of all instead of using a `Tuple<string, string>` create a proper Data Model with meaningful properties. Second, instead of manipulating UI elements in procedural code, which is probably the cause of all your performance problems because you're effectively breaking UI virtualization. Create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding, which is the correct way to work in WPF.

Comment: Thank you, but how to use a Data Model if my configuration always change? The grid is confg-able. The only different way i know is using DynamicObject, and then i need a List<> in the background again.

Comment: Why are you not using a DataTable?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx